# How to insert table filled with parentCode in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many codes and this code has many children in another table

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(150);

SET @value = '4105';

SELECT VALUE Parent 
INTO ##k 
FROM dbo.Split  (',',@value)

SELECT DISTINCT lastlevel 
INTO ##tmp_getAllLastLevel  
FROM [DWH-INF].[center].[dbo].[IFIRView_NeginTitleTotal] 
WHERE lastlevel IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level1 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level2 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level3 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level4 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level5 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level6 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level7 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k) 
   OR level8 IN (SELECT parent FROM ##k)
```

This code is ok and get all children for parent id = 4105.

But I have many parents like

```
SET @value = '4105,4106,2034,2055';
```

How can I insert all lastlevel and parent into one table like this table

```
    parent      lastlevel
------------------------------
    4105          1273
    4105          1275
    4105          1279
    4106          1288
    4106          1292
    2055          1073
```

Thanks for reading about my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use inner join like this code

```
select tb1.Parent,tb2.lastlevel into ##tmp_getAllLastLevel  from ##k 
tb1 inner join  [DWH-INF].[center].[dbo].[IFIRView_NeginTitleTotal]  tb2 on 
tb1.Parent=tb2.lastlevel or tb1.Parent=tb2.level1 or
tb1.Parent=tb2.level2 or tb1.Parent=tb2.level3 or tb1.Parent=tb2.level4 or 
tb1.Parent=tb2.level5 or tb1.Parent=tb2.level6 or tb1.Parent=tb2.level7
or tb1.Parent=tb2.level8
```

and get all parent and lastlevel

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a temporary table for this purpose:

```
select s.value as Parent, tb2.lastlevel
into ##tmp_getAllLastLevel 
from [DWH-INF].[center].[dbo].[IFIRView_NeginTitleTotal] tb2 join
     dbo.Split(',', @value) s
     on s.value in (tb2.lastlevel, tb2.level1, tb2.level2, tb2.level3, tb2.level4, tb2.level5, tb2.level6, tb2.level7, tb2.level8);
```

Also note that storing the hierarchy across columns like that might be making your queries more complicated than necessary.  You are trying to store an "array" of values as separate columns.  It is usually better (in SQL) to store them on separate rows.